# When i am trying to add expansion tile inside dropdown , it showing problem?

Tags: flutter, dart

When i am trying to add expansion tile inside drop down button, it showing error,
the actual code,

```
DropdownButton<String>(
  value: dropdownValue,
  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
  iconSize: 24,
  elevation: 16,
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.deepPurple
  ),
  underline: Container(
    height: 2,
    color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
  ),
  onChanged: (String newValue) {
    setState(() {
      dropdownValue = newValue;
    });
  },
  items: <String>[    'Option 1',    'Option 2',    'Option 3',  ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: value,
      child: ExpansionTile(
        title: Text(value),
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Expansion tile details'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }).toList(),
)
```

If anyone have ides about how to fix this one, please add your thougts The error is showing like

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#335fe relayoutBoundary=up24 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
package:flutter/…/rendering/box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 2001 pos 12: 'hasSize'
```

Comment: Wrap your expansionTile Widget with expanded widget maybe this could solve your problem

Comment: How would that work? Normally, tapping on a dropdown item selects it. Now, tapping on it expands it. How do you select it? Instead of fixing this error, maybe think about the UX and whether this is actually a good choice for a dropdown.

Comment: Yes i also agree with @nvoigt

Comment: Yeh, i am tested like this, but showing same problem, when it having normal drop down values only, no problem , issue will coming in after adding expansion tile

Comment: wrap your drop-down with expanded widget or warp with singleChildScrollView and give directions to it for horizontal and vertical

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected it for you:

```
String dropdownValue="Option 1";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SizedBox(
        height: 60,
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
  value: dropdownValue,
  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
  iconSize: 24,
  elevation: 16,
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.deepPurple
  ),
  underline: Container(
    height: 2,
    color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
  ),
  onChanged: (newValue) {
    setState(() {
        dropdownValue = newValue!;
    });
  },
  items: <String>[    'Option 1',    'Option 2',    'Option 3',  ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
    print(value);
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        value: value,
        child: SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
          height: 100,
          child: ExpansionTile(
            title: Text(value),
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Expansion tile details'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
    );
  }).toList(),
),
      )
    );
```

The problem you were facing was that the expansion tile was expanding to infinity in both the directions i.e. x and y which was causing render issues and causing the screen to go blank.